# Linq query increase performance efficient query

Tags: linq

```
int mappedCount = (from product in products 
                   from productMapping in DbContext.ProductCategoryMappings 
                                                   .Where(x => product.TenantId == x.TenantId.ToString() && 
                                                               x.ProductId.ToString().ToUpper() == product.ProductGuid.ToUpper()) 
                   join tenantCustMapping in DbContext.TenantCustCategories 
                        on productMapping.Value equals tenantCustMapping.Id 
                   select 1).ToList().Sum();
```

I need to increase the performance.

When mapping product two tables each item having multiple product

Comment: You can go store procedure. It is best given performance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase performance, you'd need to know the volumes of data that are getting sent around. How many "products" are in your variable.

It may be quicker to update your products list to contain integers / guids and send that to your database rather than send strings that the database has to run ToUpper() on before comparing them.

something like: 
var convertedList = products.Select( new {TenantId = int.parse(product.TenantId), productId = Guid.Parse(x.ProductId)}

Then sending that to your Db, and comparing them directly

I think changing "Select 1).ToList().Sum()" to ".Count()" will improve performance. Even if not, it'll help readability.